# How to import image by import as control at runtime in Livecode?

Tags: livecode

How to import image by import as control at runtime in Livecode?

I want to import an image to stack. I don't want to choose an image path. When I sent livecode file to my friend. It's have a problem with image path.

How to import image by import as control at runtime in Livecode?

Comment: I can do it.I use command "import".

Answer (score 2):

From the menu:

File > Import as control > Image File...

However, I would advise that you continue to use relative file paths and include your audio/video/image assets in the "copy files" pane of the standalone building. The primary advantage is that you can then add high resolution assets using the the format:

```
image@extra-high.png
```

LiveCode is then able to auto select the best image to use depending on the device it's running on. Retina screen vs standard screen. LiveCode will also cache the image between cards which improves transition performance between cards.